# Using a Rails JSON API as a backend for desktop app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, desktop-application, desktop, json-api

My company is wanting to use a Rails JSON API app as a backend for a desktop app. The Rails JSON API would use a Postgresql database.

However, some customers self host their data, meaning they have a postgresql server installed on a computer the desktop app uses.  Because of these users, we would have to deploy this Rails app and customers would have to run the Rails API server on their machines, including Windows machines.  Is this a good idea or even possible?

Comment: When you say 'self-hosted', what does that mean? Is there an existing web service that's providing their data? Is it on individual laptops, or is there a server providing the data? (generally just more info about the architecture will help provide a better answer)

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, but if they are set on it, they should supply a linux box as part of the product offering.  But really, its just not a great idea ...

Comment: Using a Rails app as a backend on a per desktop client basis sounds like a terrible idea, but thats not what you are contemplating? If you intend to let your customers self host you need a very clear contract detailing what technical support you provide - and what is billable time otherwise they will bleed you dry.

Comment: Self-hosted meaning they have their own postgresql server the desktop app already uses. We would attempt to ship an installer that would install a rails server on the same machine as the postgresql server.

We have a mobile app and web product that we offer our customers (who we host their data) which already uses a Rails API.  I think the thought of this would be to make it more consistent.

Comment: I would really encourage them to use a VM image that you provide. Having to deploy to multiple OS:es (especially The One That Shall Not Be Named) sounds like a nightmare. In theory cross platform is easy, in reality the fact that the underlying system is built on duct tape, popsicle sticks and unicorn farts and uses the wrong path sepator tends to rear its ugly head up on every deploy. I have fortunately never had to do it with Ruby, but doing PHP on IIS has left me with no appetite to try it.

Comment: @max our customers only have one server, they either host it themselves or we host it.  If they host it, then they can have other clients connect to the server, but in most cases they only have one machine really using the desktop app.

Comment: What product? The desktop application or the Rails API? If your client wants to self host for cost reasons I would take that as serious warning that this might be a project that you might want to pass on.

Comment: Sorry, I meant desktop app, that would be using the Rails API.

Answer (score 0):

If your customers are running the db themselves, you probably don't need an api, right?

Otoh, there are tools like portable ruby by the phusion team that let you pacakge up a Ruby app.  You can also build the app via JRuby as a jar or war and deploy that in any env with Java

Comment: I have the same view.  I don't think it needs an API.  Also the thought of having to install some kind of rails server along with the postgres server makes me really nervous and don't think it would be a pleasant experience.  But the big reason behind this is to make the database connection consistent across all the products we have (desktop app, mobile app, and web app).